# Capacitive touch: Multi-touch (Simultaneous Read) Self-capacitance Buttons with Single Capacitive Touch Interface IC

Tags: capacitor, switches, touchscreen

With capacitive touch, if I want multiple independent buttons rather than a screen, will multi-touch (ability to register more than one button simultaneously) still be prevented with self-capacitance buttons rather than mutual-capacitance buttons due to shared ground pad, when using a single interface IC?

Comment: wouldn't that be dependent on how it was designed?

Comment: @jsotola : i should have added: with a single capacitive touch interface IC : j